# SQL Datediff overflow - Null overflows

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, integer-overflow

I am running a datediff to return microsecond diffs between two timestamps, so I believe the greatest gap that can be handled pre-overflow is about 33 minutes.

There *are* going to be a number of reasons why a 33+ minute gap would appear, and these are *not* of concern to me. They fall outside my range of analysis. I was expecting some functionality to ignore any overflows as a result and I came across:

```
set arithabort off
set ansi_warnings off
set arithignore on
```

My understanding is that these should suppress warnings and prevent abortion of the query, returning a NULL where an overflow would happen.

However, actually using these in the query still results in:

```
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
```

I am slightly confused. Is a datediff overflow not an arithmetic overflow? Is there a different 'set' hint that I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the overflows, but you can use `case`:

```
select (case when datediff(second, t1, t2) > 30
             then cast(datediff(second, t1, t2) as bigint) * 1000000
             else cast(datediff(microsecond, t1, t2) as bigint)
        end)
```